# How to get the entry with newest date for each value of another variable

Tags: r

I have a dataset like the following:

```js
X                   Designname       Authorname Votes AvgScore SubmitDate year day week.of.the.year wk.list before.after Print  Challenge
1   1685                   final-boss        jameses_x   591     3.47 2013-04-01 2013 Mon               14       1       before     1 Threadless
2  73684                      favella            yooka   348     2.72 2013-04-01 2013 Mon               14       1       before     0 Threadless
3  73687            watch-your-back-2        sayahelmi   481     3.15 2013-04-01 2013 Mon               14       1       before     0 Threadless
4  73688              smoking-kills-5  Professor Vince   379     2.19 2013-04-01 2013 Mon               14       1       before     0 Threadless
5  73689         meet-professor-vince  Professor Vince   339     2.07 2013-04-01 2013 Mon               14       1       before     0 Threadless
6  73690         master-of-disguise-2          Mundara   331     2.81 2013-04-01 2013 Mon               14       1       before     0 Threadless
7  73691                      lion-15             a7md   401     3.08 2013-04-01 2013 Mon               14       1       before     0 Threadless
8  73692                 zen-attitude       kharmazero   368     2.95 2013-04-01 2013 Mon               14       1       before     0 Threadless
9  73694       turn-the-other-cheek-3 Laurence Jenkins   303     2.26 2013-04-01 2013 Mon               14       1       before     0 Threadless
10 73695                 fantasy-park          zsonzsy   519     3.43 2013-04-01 2013 Mon               14       1       before     0 Threadless
11 73696                swiss-plumber        diVulture   330     2.92 2013-04-01 2013 Mon               14       1       before     0 Threadless
12 73699                       impala              108   372     2.95 2013-04-01 2013 Mon               14       1       before     0 Threadless
13 73700 catastrophe-divide-by-zero-2       Shadyjibes   323     2.74 2013-04-01 2013 Mon               14       1       before     0 Threadless
14 73701 catastrophe-divide-by-zero-2       BootsBoots   323     2.74 2013-04-01 2013 Mon               14       1       before     0 Threadless
15 73702                       inking          mainial   465     3.31 2013-04-01 2013 Mon               14       1       before     0 Threadless
16 73707                  chloroville         Sebcbien   304     2.67 2013-04-01 2013 Mon               14       1       before     0 Threadless
17 73708                  warter-guns        Gamma-Ray   413     3.21 2013-04-01 2013 Mon               14       1       before     0 Threadless
18 73712                       labori         BRLNVCTM   231     2.05 2013-04-01 2013 Mon               14       1       before     0 Threadless
19 73715              kunimitsus-mask       FlourKirby   307     2.51 2013-04-01 2013 Mon               14       1       before     0 Threadless
20 73722                      dmantis      cuss pahing   322     2.94 2013-04-01 2013 Mon               14       1       before     0 Threadless
```

And I want to get the latest SubmitDate for each Authorname (the maximum date of each Author).

I have tried the following code:

```
 agg = aggregate(SubmitDate ~ Authorname, data = sub.before.design, max)
```

It looks like this line of code is working.

However, the number of authors in agg does not match the number of the authors in the original data frame.

In the original data frame, I have more than 11,000 unique Authornames. In agg, there are only about 8000 authors.

I am wondering where I went wrong, or if there are any other ways to get the results I want.

Comment: Try `aggregate(SubmiteDate ~ Authorname, data=sub.before.design, max, na.action=na.pass)` - I'm guessing you have `NA` values for some of the dates, and `aggregate` skips those when you use the `y ~ x` formula method.

Comment: In case @thelatemail's answer did not hit the mark, please provide a reproducible example so that we are not left to make educated guesses.

Comment: Here's a `dplyr` version: `agg <- summarise(group_by(sub.before.design, Authorname), lastdate = last(SubmitDate, order_by(SubmitDate)))`.